# Best way to index json objects in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine

What is the best way to index elastic search json documents?

I'm new to elsticsearch, i would like to know best way to index josn, as a single large document with all children objects embedded in it  or with parent child relationship.

if all child objects embedded in a single document is it possible to filter the few child document and get along with parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the _bulk api for indexing json documents. If the json objects follow the same schema then you could put them in the same type or else divide them into different types.

Bulk API :

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/{indexName}/{typeName}/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": 2, "parent": "london" }}
{ "name": "Mark Thomas", "dob": "1982-05-16", "hobby": "diving" }
{ "index": { "_id": 3, "parent": "liverpool" }}
{ "name": "Barry Smith", "dob": "1979-04-01", "hobby": "hiking" }
{ "index": { "_id": 4, "parent": "paris" }}
{ "name": "Adrien Grand", "dob": "1987-05-11", "hobby": "horses" }
```

Here you could define the parent field for each document. Mind you the parent field should already be present among the documents.

Read more about bulkk api here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html
https://people.mozilla.org/~wkahngreene/elastic/guide/reference/api/bulk.html

Comment: Thanks @Amriteya. Do you have any examples on how to aggregate parent and child